# How to change logger level (warning, info, debug) for Idempiere logs

Tags: idempiere

I have few debugs with info in the java class configured in Idempiere plugin. But after execution of that class on that server, I am getting warning log, but not info log, inside idempiere logs.
I tried google but couldn't find anything related to it. Could some one help in "How to change logger level (warning, info, debug) for Idempiere logs"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the iDempiere Monitor

```
http://127.0.0.0:8080/idempiereMonitor
```

You can access with your **System User** credentials. Then go to the line:

```
Trace Log Level
```

And select one of these:

1. OFF
2. SEVERE
3. WARNING
4. INFO
5. CONFIG
6. FINE
7. FINER
8. FINEST
9. ALL

This will regenerate the last log file and build the new ones with this parameter.